# Pass a list to a stored procedure in linQ to sql

Tags: stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I defined table type "Int array" in T-SQL and use it as a stored procedure input parameter.

I wrote this code:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name = "[dbo].sp_GetAllLicense ")]
[ResultType(typeof(sp_GetAllLicenseResult))]
[ResultType(typeof(int))]

public IMultipleResults sp_GetAllLicense(
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "FromDate", DbType = "NVarChar(10)")] string fromDate,
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "EndDate", DbType = "NVarChar(10)")] string endDate, 
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "License", DbType = "int")] int a, 
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "City", DbType = "Structured")] IEnumerable <int> City,
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "ProductID", DbType = "Structured")] IEnumerable<int> ProductID, 
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "NoeFaaliat", DbType = "Structured")] IEnumerable<int> NoeFaaliat)

{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), fromDate, endDate,a,City,ProductID,NoeFaaliat );
    return (IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue);
}
```

City, productID and activity are my 3 int array parameters, that I can't work with them.

I change their "DBType" and their type but now I get this error:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a list 1 to an IEnumerable`1

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Dear marc,as you see I use sp_ befor my store procedure. sp_GetAllLicense is my store procedure.

Comment: i didnt see NOT.ok thank you